# why does "echo -n" command not work in a .sh script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

For example, I'm writing a script in a .sh file, and I want to echo the phrase "string" without a trailing whitespace/new line, so I should probably use `echo -n "string"` like how I would achieve this function in bash or zsh. However, when I run the .sh in bash/zsh with `sh` command the .sh file would just print `-n string`, with a new line included. How do I print something without trailing new line whilst also using the `echo` command?

Comment: Use `printf`.  Implementations of `echo` are a hodge-podge of non-standardness.

Comment: If you insist on using `echo`, the only really reliable thing to do is to trim the newline: `echo string | tr -d \\n`.  But you're much better off with `printf string`

Answer (score 1):

`bash`'s implementation of the `echo` command differs wildly from the POSIX specification.  When `bash` is run as `sh`, `echo` behaves *more* like POSIX intends, but your `sh` may also *not* be `bash`, but a shell like `dash` that adheres more strictly to the POSIX specification, which does not allow for any extensions. POSIX requires `-n` to be treated like any other argument, something to be output rather than modifying the behavior of `echo`.

Use `printf` instead, which has a tighter POSIX specification and is much more portable.

```
printf 'string'
```